# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to 1} \dfrac{\sin(3x^2 - 5x + 2)}{x^2+x-2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

> How to evaluate the following limit without using the L'Hôspital rule?
>   $$ \lim_{x\to 1} \dfrac{\sin(3x^2 - 5x + 2)}{x^2+x-2} $$

Comment: $3x^2-5x+2=(x-1)(3x-2)$ and $x^2+x-2=(x-1)(x+2)$.

Comment: Divide the top and bottom by $x-1$ and use the definition of the derivative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

using the fact that $\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \sin { x }  }{ x }  } =1\\ $ we get 
$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 1 }{ \frac { \sin { \left( 3{ x }^{ 2 }-5x+2 \right)  }  }{ { x }^{ 2 }+x-2 }  } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 1 }{ \frac { \sin { \left( 3{ x }^{ 2 }-5x+2 \right)  }  }{ 3{ x }^{ 2 }-5x+2 } \frac { 3{ x }^{ 2 }-5x+2 }{ { x }^{ 2 }+x-2 }  } =\\ =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 1 }{ \frac { \left( x-1 \right) \left( 3x-2 \right)  }{ \left( x+2 \right) \left( x-1 \right)  }  } =\frac { 1 }{ 3 }  $$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$
\frac{\sin(3x^2 - 5x + 2)}{x^2+x-2} = \frac{\sin(3x^2 - 5x + 2)}{3x^2 - 5x + 2}\cdot \frac{3x^2 - 5x + 2}{x^2+x-2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to1} \frac{\sin(3x^2 - 5x + 2)}{x^2+x-2}=\lim_{x\to1} \frac{\sin(x-1)(3x-2)}{(x-1)(3x-2)}\times\dfrac{(3x-2)}{(x+2)}=\dfrac13$$